# Can I "kitbash" normal/bump maps with brushes?

Tags: texture-painting, normal-map, bump

I am thinking it may be possible to paint onto normal or bump maps "kitbashing" details to not have geometry as I have seen people like Jayanam do this manually but only for basic dents etc.

Is there a way or a brush kit to do this sort of work or is it not really viable as an option, if it is what sort of brushes would I use (difference etc).

I have some with bolts and buttons for sculpting but not much and don't really know the process or if the sculpt brush is different to normal map painting brushes etc.

Comment: Bumps, yes, but you need to do a lot of work baking out images to use as a brush. The good thing is that if you rename them as a continuous sequence that you can load the image sequence as a texture brush and then use the timeline to shuffle through the images.

Comment: As an addition to the above: tangent space normal maps can't easily be rotated.

Comment: @CraigDJones I think that one's worthy of an answer  ..

Comment: Maybe I will have time to put together an example later as an answer, the comment is just a pointer.

Comment: Yeah, i'm not advanced enough to know what your talking about, sorry (baking brushes? continuous sequence?Timeline shufling? lost me).